# Crystal Reports with Windows 7 - Report displays with a huge left margin inside viewer

Tags: windows-7, crystal-reports

I really hope someone can help me here. I have tried applying SP1 to Visual Studio 2008 and SP1 to Crystal Reports Basic that comes with VB2008 to repair this problem, but have had no success. I've tried setting margins, changing paper sizes and default printers too.. No joy.

Every time I create a ReportViewer and give it a ReportDocument in Windows 7, the report isn't centered in the ReportViewer. If I resize the width of the window to the point you can see the whole page of the report, theres a huge section of background to the left. I was originally coding under Windows XP (the error doesn't occur in XP but does occur on some client systems running Windows 7), but after swapping my coding environment over to Windows 7 this error even occurs at design stage! Please help if you can.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]
http://i55.tinypic.com/53o135.jpg

As you can see in this screenshot, there is no Crystal Report Viewer background visible on the right, yet there is already a large section visible on the left. Once the window is enlarged further, the left becomes even larger still.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Crystal XI under Windows XP, but I think I can answer your question.

In the image below (taken from your image), the white space circled in red holds your **Group Tree**.  Click on the icon above it (with the red arrow) to hide the group tree.

The grey space (circled in green) tells you the **Section Names**, i.e. Header, Group Footer, etc.  To turn that off, go into **File->Options->Layout**.

Does this answer your question, I hope? Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying but hiding the group tree only gives me a group tree worth of extra width- I'm hiding it in my actual project :) argh hitting enter is posting the comment! umm the screenshot is from Visual Studio 2008 (that has Crystal Reports Basic 10.5 included) - it doesn't have a File > Options menu, and doesn't have "layout" in the Visual Basic menus. Also running this program under Windows XP displays no grey space, and never displays section names there - I'm a little confused as to where that information came from. Perhaps Crystal XI has its own report viewer editor but VB doesn't :(

Comment: Also this issue is specific to Windows 7 (Crystal Report Runtime I think). Under XP there is no grey area as illustrated, both during design stage and even if I compile it in Windows 7 looking dodgy as above then run it on XP. Running the program on XP shows no grey area! >.<

Comment: To clarify, my instructions are for the standalone Designer where (I think) there's also an option to hide the section names entirely.  When I posted this yesterday, I assumed the VS2008 was sufficiently similar. Perhaps not.  Good luck with the problem.

Comment: I do appreciate you taking the time to reply mate. Sadly VB takes on the role of the designer, as it has a wacky inbuilt version of Crystal Reports but many thanks all the same :)

Comment: Just in case others have this problem too, I've found something that can be played with to maybe solve the problem though it's really random..I have a report that contains a blob field. I'm filling that field with a jpg image at program runtime. When the image filled is larger than the paper width, the report appears in the correct position. The reason it's random is I haven't tested it further and the blob was appearing on the second page of the report due to keeptogether. The first page displays incorrectly, then the second page with the oversized image fixes the problem on that page only!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution to this problem. It's when the user selects 120% magnified objects in their Windows Display settings! You need to adjust things for the DPI change